# Build job in Jenkins through python script

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins

I want to Trigger an Build Job in Jenkins through python-jenkins package.I used the Below code for test_api job but it is not working.How can i Build through Script..

```
import jenkins
j = jenkins.Jenkins('http://your_url_here', 'username', 'password')
print j.get_jobs()
url=j.build_job_url('test_api', parameters=None, token=None)
print url
last_build_number = j.get_job_info('test_api')['lastCompletedBuild'] ['number']
print "last_build_number",last_build_number
build_info=j.get_build_info('test_api',last_build_number)
if build_info['result']=='SUCCESS':
    print " Build Success "
else:
    print " Build Failed "
    log=j.get_build_console_output('test_api',last_build_number)
    f=open('log_buildFail.txt','w')
    f.write(log)
    f.close()
```

It returns the Build url path after the build.

Answer (score 5):

I am using `build_job` method to trigger a job and it works for me.

```
build_job(name, parameters=None, token=None)
    Trigger build job.

    Parameters: 
    name – name of job
    parameters – parameters for job, or None, dict
    token – Jenkins API token
```

Here is an example of mine:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8
import jenkins
ci_jenkins_url = "http://my-jenkins-url/"
username = "foo"
token = "fa818f4f90621a4e69de563516098689"
job = "test-job"
j = jenkins.Jenkins(ci_jenkins_url, username=username, password=token)

if __name__ == "__main__":
      j.build_job(job, {'token': token})
```

You can get token from http://my-jenkins-url/user/foo/configure and then click `show API Token...`.
For those who are new to Jenkins Python API,
 please reference to [Jenkins Python API Link](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-jenkins).

Comment: I used the build_job instead of build_job_url ,but when checked in jenkins build is not triggered.

Comment: Is there is anything to be Configured in Jenkins like Jenkins API token,to Trigger Build.

Comment: I am getting the Following Error with jenkins token :`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Jenkins_Build.py", line 33, in <module>
    url=j.build_job('test_job',{'token':'8f2f933f9602fcd7cd9a4970bde6cd5c'})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkins\__init__.py", line 456, in build_job
    self.build_job_url(name, parameters, token)))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkins\__init__.py", line 218, in jenkins_open
    'Possibly authentication failed [%s]' % (e.code)
JenkinsException: Error in request.Possibly authentication failed [500]`

Comment: Do I require admin permissions to Build this ??

Comment: No. No `admin` permission needed. Any authorized user can do this.  As described in its API doc, you got an `JenkinsException` might due to incorrect username/password/url/timeout condition met.

Comment: my username ,password and url is correct  Because  i am getting output for j.get_jobs() and get_build_info()functions.

Comment: you need to set the token like the above example when calling the `build_job` function